# I want to count many inputs javascript and submit to mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, html, count

my code actually works for the first input that comes with the original html code, but when I add a row it doesn't count them. and I also want to show a php var in javascript. Finally I want to post the added rows to a table using mysqli

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h3 align="center">
    <?php echo $products; ?>
  </h3>
  <table align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $code; ?>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $product; ?>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $quantity.' '.$total; ?> <a href="showproducts.php" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-edit text-danger"></i></a></th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $quantity; ?>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $price.' '.$unit; ?>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">
          <?php echo $price.' '.$total; ?>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="codebar" onchange="codefetch()" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="product" onchange="autofill()" id="prodname" class="form-control form-control-sm" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo $prodname; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class=""><input id="quantity" name="quantity" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
      <td><input id="neededquantity" name="neededquantity" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
      <td><input id="sellprice" name="sellprice" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm sellprice"></td>
      <td><input id="totalprice" name="totalprice" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="orderTable">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <center style="padding:10px;">
    <button id="add" style="width:150px;" onclick="addRow()" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    <button id="remove" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
  </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
function autofill() {

  var name = $('input[name=product]').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'gpin.php',
    data: 'name=' + name,
    success: function(data) {
      var json = data;
      obj = JSON.parse(json);
      $('input[name=quantity]').val(obj.quantity);
      $('input[name=sellprice]').val(obj.sellprice);
      $('input[name=codebar]').val(obj.code);
    }
  });
}

function codefetch() {
  var code = $("input[name=codebar]").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'gpic.php',
    data: 'code=' + code,
    success: function(data) {
      var json = data;
      obj = JSON.parse(json);
      $('input[name=product]').val(obj.name);
      $('input[name=quantity]').val(obj.quantity);
      $('input[name=sellprice]').val(obj.sellprice);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#prodname').typeahead({
    source: function(query, result) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "prodnameautofill.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          query: query
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          result($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
          }));
        }
      })
    }
  });

});


function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = $('input[name=neededquantity]').val();
  var myBox2 = $('input[name=sellprice]').val();
  var result = $('input[name=totalprice]').val();
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  $('input[name=totalprice]').val(myResult);
  var quantity = $('input[name=quantity]').val();
  var neededquantity = $('input[name=neededquantity]').val();
  var myResult2 = quantity - neededquantity;
  if (myResult2 < 0) {
    document.getElementsByName('neededquantity').className = ('form-control form-control-sm bg-danger text-light');
  } else {
    document.getElementsByName('neededquantity')[0].className = ('form-control form-control-sm bg-success text-light');
  }
}

function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input name="codebar" onchange="codefetch()" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="product" onchange="autofill()" id="prodname" class="form-control form-control-sm" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo $prodname; ?>" />';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input name="quantity" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">';
  cell4.innerHTML = '<input name="neededquantity" type="text" oninput="calculate();" class="form-control form-control-sm">';
  cell5.innerHTML = '<input name="sellprice" type="text" oninput="calculate();" class="form-control form-control-sm sellprice">';
  cell6.innerHTML = '<input name="totalprice" readonly type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">';
}
```

and is it possible to echo a php variable in javascript as I intended to do in my jscode

```
cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="product" onchange="autofill()" id="prodname" class="form-control form-control-sm" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo $prodname; ?>" />';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically PHP works before page exist(only so it's done when page is screened) and JavaScript is in the page when browser read it so no communication are possible. Instead you've to use AJAX who can meet them with asyncronymous calls + meta-datas such XML or JSON files or meta-files.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i know tgis and i will use php only to insert into the db